# Django Rest Framework API sets image to default image even if user uploads an image

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

When I try to create a new user through DRF, the avatar field displays the default image even if the user uploads an image. When I try to create a user with an image through the admin panel it works fine. So I'm assuming that I'm missing something in my serializer.

Custom User Model

```
class myAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email')
        
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an username')
        
        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            username=username,
        )
        user.is_admin=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg')
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = myAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin
    
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

User serializer

```
UserModel = User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):

        user = UserModel.objects.create_user(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            password=validated_data['password'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
        )

        return user

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        # Tuple of serialized model fields (see link [2])
        fields = ( "id", "email", "username", "password", "avatar")
```

Static file path

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static'
]

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR /'static/images'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the serializer's `create()` method. You were not passing the `avatar` data into the **`create_user(...)`** method. So, update your method as below,

```
from rest_framework import serializers

UserModel = User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return UserModel.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        # Tuple of serialized model fields (see link [2])
        fields = ("id", "email", "username", "password", "avatar")
```